# Imported code from another developer: <No resource identifier found for attribute 'ProgressColor' in package...> error in one of my .xml files

Tags: android, xml

This is the .xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:seekarc="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.pelkinsoft.enpower"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
```

The errors occur at:

```
    <com.triggertrap.seekarc.SeekArc
        android:id="@+id/seekArc"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="30dp"
        seekarc:progressColor="@color/arc_color"
        seekarc:rotation="180"
        seekarc:startAngle="30"
        seekarc:sweepAngle="300"
        seekarc:touchInside="true" />
```

I am new to Android and this is keeping me from being able to effectively work on this app.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add the Seek Arc library (https://github.com/neild001/SeekArc#adding-to-your-project) to your project

Answer (score 1):

Inside res foder, create following file:

```
res/values/color.xml
```

Then, define the color used by SeekArc view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
     <color name="arc_color">#0000FF</color>
</resources>
```

**OR**

Manually set the color in the SeekArk view:

```
<com.triggertrap.seekarc.SeekArc
    android:id="@+id/seekArc"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    ....
    seekarc:progressColor="#0000FF"
    ....
    />
```